Google Analytics 4 API sampling level parameter?
Google Analytics UA v3 and v4 APIs had the samplingLevel parameter https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#sampling
I cannot locate the same for Google Analytics 4 data API
Does it exist?
I have a relatively simple query - date, session campaign name, some metrics.
This query is fine, but if I introduce campaign id I get sampling. It's bizzare because I would imagine that campaign name and campaign id have similar cardinality.

You can find sampling information in ResponseMetaData:
{
 "dataLossFromOtherRow": boolean,
 "samplingMetadatas": [
   {
     object (SamplingMetadata)
   }
  ],
 "schemaRestrictionResponse": {
   object (SchemaRestrictionResponse)
 },
 "currencyCode": string,
 "timeZone": string,
 "emptyReason": string,
 "subjectToThresholding": boolean
}

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/ResponseMetaData?hl=en

yes I understand that the response can contain information about sampling; what I am asking is for the request parameter that reduced sampling, which was available in universal analytics

There isn't (now)

samplingLevel has just been added to the runReportTask method

runReportTask method is currently in v1alpha, anyway there isn't samplingLevel information
